# Como fazer vários SUM dentro da mesma query no MS SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alguém sabe como realizar diversas somas com diferentes quantidades de linhas na mesma Query ?
Preciso fazer um top 100, 200, 300, 400 949 itens mais vendidos. Porém precisam estar todos dentro da mesma query. Estou utilizando SD2010 (D2_Total) para essa query. Vlw

Comment: Se vc precisa dos top 100, 200, 300, 400 949 itens mais vendidos na mesma query, então bastaria colocar os 949, pois logicamente os 100, 200, 300, 400 vão estar lá dentro...

Comment: Então, mas a query é basicamente isso, ter uma coluna que traga os 949, ao lado, 400, ao lado 300, 200 e 100. Coisa de chefe ...

Comment: Suspeito que você precisa fazer uma view com vários subselect dentro. Porém não tem como dar uma resposta legal, pois a sua pergunta não está sendo clara. Melhore ela e certamente terá respostas bem interessantes. [Dicas aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: ~@RickydeCamargo: vc está querendo uma coluna com a soma do faturamento dos top 100, ao lado dos top 200, etc..., é isso?

Comment: @RicardoMerinhoFernandes isso !!! O total de linhas são 949 na query principal. Agora preciso deixar além das 949 que já vem naturalmente, uma coluna com 100, uma com 200, outra com 300 e uma com 400 maior faturamento.

Comment: Como seria a visualização?!

Comment: @motta 
codigo, descrição, qtd vendas, soma top 949, soma top 400, soma top 300, soma top 200, soma top100

Comment: eu faria : uma sql gerando uma tabela virtual com analytic function gerando um RANK , lendo esta tabela e fazendo o PIVOT com CASE , algo como sum(case when rank < 101 then valor else 0 end) valortop100.... consegui passar minha idieia ?

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver essa situação, siga estas etapas:

1. Monte a query para fazer a soma pela faixa de quantidade. Exemplo os "100":

```
SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY) as teste
```

2. Por fora dela, monte um sum para agrupar eles. Aí, vc já deixa uma "espera" para as outras faixas. Exemplo:

```
select sum(quantidade) quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, 0 quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY) as teste
```

3. Repita o processo para todas as faixas e use o UNION para juntar tudo em uma querie. Exemplo:

```
select sum(quantidade) quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, 0 
quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY) as teste
UNION
select 0 quantidade100, sum(quantidade) quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, 0     
quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY) as teste
UNION
select 0 quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, sum(quantidade) quantidade300, 0     
quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order         
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 300 ROWS ONLY) as teste
UNION
select 0 quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, sum(quantidade) 
quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 400 ROWS ONLY) as teste
UNION
select 0 quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, 0 quantidade400, 
sum(quantidade) quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 900 ROWS ONLY) as teste
```

4. Por fim, é só fazer um sum de cada faixa de valor que ficará tudo em uma mesma linha. Exemplo:

```
SELECT sum(quantidade100)quantidade100,sum(quantidade200)quantidade200,sum(quantidade300)quantidade300,sum(quantidade400)quantidade400,sum(quantidade900)quantidade900 from
(select sum(quantidade) quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, 0 
quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY) as teste
UNION
select 0 quantidade100, sum(quantidade) quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, 0 
quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY) as teste
UNION
select 0 quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, sum(quantidade) quantidade300, 0 
quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 300 ROWS ONLY) as teste
UNION
select 0 quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, sum(quantidade) 
quantidade400, 0 quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 400 ROWS ONLY) as teste
UNION
select 0 quantidade100, 0 quantidade200, 0 quantidade300, 0 quantidade400, 
sum(quantidade) quantidade900 from 
(SELECT produto,sum(quantidade) as quantidade FROM test group by produto order 
by 2 desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 900 ROWS ONLY) as teste) as teste1
```

Seguindo esses passos, vc não precisará de views ou qualquer outro objeto adicional, apenas codificação SQL.